# android update view upon event in singleton class

Tags: android, ios, listview, android-listview, singleton

I am new to android development and am actually not sure about what exact term to be searching for this scenario. I have a singleton class which does some music play back stuff and I have 3 other list views in tabs which contain music tracks. Depending upon which track is playing in the singleton, I want that row in one or more of the list views to change backgroundColor to yellow and other ones to go white.
How should I perform something like this?

I don't want to refresh/reload the entire list every time the track changes.

Should I be iterating through every single row to check against the singleton if it's the one playing? That could be resource consuming if a lot of rows exist. Or a better way? can some xml+java magic be used? What's the best way to perform this sort of thing in other languages like iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Call `<ListAdapter>.notifyDataSetChanged();` to notify the `ListView` that it should be refreshed, where  is the adapter instance that was passed to the `ListView`. This will *not* iterate through every item in the list, but only the currently visible ones.

With the proper recycling of inflated view and the use of [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html), the overhead for updating a list can be kept to a minimum.